Method Illuminate\View\ComponentAttributeBag::extractPropNames does not exist
I've been working on updating my Laravel 10 app to version 11, and after switching back to the working branch, I now get this error.
It's occurring wherever a blade file uses the @props directive.
As far as I can tell, the method does exist... I'm wondering whether it's referencing it from the wrong location though.
Any help debugging would be appreciated.

"switching back to the working branch" - what exactly does that mean? Using Laravel 10 again? What does the stacktrace tell you about where the error is coming from?

everything seems fine on the first sight. have you tried clearing the cache?
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear

or all-in one optimize
php artisan optimize:clear

just to be sure. or run a fresh composer install again, something might get broken (or missing or filesystem permissions or something) during installing the composer packages

php artisan view:clear was the solution here... thanks
